Synchronize Supabase types with Zod to validate data in API routes
Context
I'm building a Next.js application with TypeScript and Supabase as my backend. Supabase CLI automatically generates TypeScript types from my database schema, which look like this:
export type Database = {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      ingredients: {
        Row: {
          calories: number | null
          carbohydrates: number | null
          created_at: string
          fiber: number | null
          id: number
          lipids: number | null
          name: string
          proteins: number | null
          saturated_fat: number | null
          sodium: number | null
          sugars: number | null
        }
        Insert: {
          calories?: number | null
          carbohydrates?: number | null
          created_at?: string
          fiber?: number | null
          id?: number
          lipids?: number | null
          name: string
          proteins?: number | null
          saturated_fat?: number | null
          sodium?: number | null
          sugars?: number | null
        }
        Update: {
          calories?: number | null
          carbohydrates?: number | null
          created_at?: string
          fiber?: number | null
          id?: number
          lipids?: number | null
          name?: string
          proteins?: number | null
          saturated_fat?: number | null
          sodium?: number | null
          sugars?: number | null
        }
      }
      // ... other tables
    }
  }
}

Problem
I want to use Zod to validate data in my API requests, but I don't want to manually maintain the schemas in sync with my Supabase types. I need a way to:

Automatically generate Zod schemas from the Supabase types
Keep the schemas in sync when the database schema changes

Current approach
Currently, I'm manually creating my Zod schemas like this:
export const ingredientSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, "Ingredient name is required"),
  calories: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  carbohydrates: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  fiber: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  lipids: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  proteins: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  saturated_fat: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  sodium: z.number().nullable().optional(),
  sugars: z.number().nullable().optional(),
});

But this approach is:

Error-prone: I might miss fields when the database schema changes
Redundant: I'm essentially duplicating type information
Hard to maintain: Changes need to be made in multiple places

Question
What's the best way to automatically generate Zod schemas from Supabase-generated types while still allowing custom validation rules? Is there a utility or pattern that could help with this?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
